# Nearest number of neighbors on 2d regular grid

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a large array of 2d points, e.g.:

```
SeedRandom[1];

nPoints = 100000;

xmin = 0; ymin = 15;
xmax = 45; ymax = 32;

points = Transpose[{RandomReal[{xmin, xmax}, nPoints],
                    RandomReal[{ymin, ymax}, nPoints]}
                  ];
```

Now **I want to count the `number` of neighbouring points within a certain `radius` throughout a regular grid in certain steps** (`dx` and `dy`).

My simple counting code ist the following:

```
number = Array[0 &, {Round@((xmax - xmin)/dx), Round@((ymax - ymin)/dy)}];

dx = 0.125; dy = 0.125;
radius = 2.;

Do[
   Do[
     number[[i, j]] = 
        Length@Nearest[points, {xmin + (i - 1)*dx + dx/2, ymin + (j - 1)*dy + dy/2}, 
           {All, radius}];
     , {j, 1, Round@((ymax - ymin)/dy), 1}
     ];
   , {i, 1, Round@((xmax - xmin)/dx), 1}
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

{22.7748, Null}
```

The corresponding `ListDensityPlot` of `number` can be plotted with:

```
ListDensityPlot[Transpose@number, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

The color represents regions of a certain `number` of points within `radius`.

Since I have to process the Do loops a few thousand times this solution is simply far too slow.

**What is a fastest possible solution to calculate the Array `number`?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's already a very good idea to use `Nearest`. You can improve that a little by defining the `NearestFunction` once. Moreover, a `NearestFunction` knows its input dimension so that it can automatically thread over its input. No loop constructs needed. Using also `points-> Automatic` releaves `Nearest` from the duty of reading all the coordinates from `points`. On my machine, this leads to a 15-fold speedup:

```
nPoints = 100000;
xmin = 0.; ymin = 15.; xmax = 45.; ymax = 32.;
points = Transpose[{RandomReal[{xmin, xmax}, nPoints], 
    RandomReal[{ymin, ymax}, nPoints]}];
dx = .125;
dy = .125;
radius = 2.;

grid = Developer`ToPackedArray@Table[
    {x, y},
    {x, xmin + dx/2, xmax, dx},
    {y, ymin + dy/2, ymax, dy}
    ];
number2 = Map[Length, Nearest[points-> Automatic, grid, {All, radius}], {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

number = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[grid][[1 ;; 2]]];
Do[Do[number[[i, j]] = 
       Length@Nearest[
         points, {xmin + (i - 1)*dx + dx/2, 
          ymin + (j - 1)*dy + dy/2}, {All, radius}];, {j, 1, 
      Round@((ymax - ymin)/dy), 1}];, {i, 1, Round@((xmax - xmin)/dx),
     1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
number == number2
```

> {1.62238, Null}
>
> {24.2462, Null}
>
> True

**Edit**

Setting `nPoints = 1000000` leads to a pretty bad blow up of memory usage (not to mention runtime). Clearly, it is suboptimal to store the list of all points within given radius around each grid point when we only require the length of these lists...

The following is slightly slower but more robust under cranking up `nPoints`. The idea is to find for each point in `points` the `grid` points with distance lower than `radius` and to add 1 to the corresponding positions in `gridcounter`. Moreover, its still persisting high memory requirements can easily be adressed by cutting `points` into smaller chunks and handing over these chunks to the `NearestFunction` one after another.

```
number3 = Module[{g, gridcounters, data},
    g = Nearest[Flatten[grid, 1] -> Automatic];
    gridcounters = ConstantArray[0, Times @@ Dimensions[grid]];
    data = g[points, {All, radius}];
    Do[gridcounters[[idxlist]] += 1;, {idxlist, data}];
    g =.;
    data =.;
    ArrayReshape[gridcounters, Dimensions[grid][[1 ;; 2]]]
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
    number3 == number2
```

> {2.27033, Null}
>
> True

**Another remark**

If you are also satisfied with square-shaped balls (balls with respect to the $\infty$-norm) then you could also apply `BinCounts` in conjunction with a suitable scaling.

Comment: Thank you ... sorry I forgot to set `dx, dy, radius` - I updated my question with the values that you have chosen. btw you can replace `Max[Abs[number - number2]]` by `number == number2` which gives `True`.

Comment: Yes, with integer matrices,  `==` is a good way. But with real matrices, this leads often to false negatives. So, it's just a habit of mine.

Comment: Both of your solutions, especially where you caclulate `number3,` are very sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks! (I hope that is meant positively...)

Comment: Absolutely ... I never thought about the memory usage problem and also your idea to search for each point the corresponding grid point is interesting. And finally the performance of your solution is much better. Once again ... thanks a lot for the code.

Comment: Hello Henrik ... I would be very happy if you could have a look at the following question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163972/radial-distribution-function-pair-correlation-function-for-particles-in-rectan